# some proplems about test openimscore

Tags: ims

Is there any good choose to test the openimscore like OpenIC_Lite or x-lite 、uctimsclient, I have tried all of them, but not succeed in installing them on ubuntu16 or windows?

1. I can't find the OpenIC_Lite package, because of the link
   http://www.fokus.fraunhofer.de/testbeds/ims_playground/components/openic_download/OpenIC_Lite.tar.gz
   seems not to provide the package
2. I have got the x-lite exe package in
   https://gsf-fl.softonic.com/7eb/91d/07ddf7568b3cda042bc3119ab7b48ce264/X-Lite_4-9-2_79048.exe?Expires=1576275140&Signature=dec4c792593f591b064de103298239f1db513afd&url=https://x-lite.en.softonic.com&Filename=X-Lite_4-9-2_79048.exe
   , after I installed the package on win10 and run the x-lite, there is
   a notice about "X-Lite Update required".

   https://img-blog.csdnimg.cn/20191214182533682.png
3. And I have tried the uctismclient, I get the package in
   https://liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net/project/uctimsclient.berlios/uctimsclient1.0.14.tar.gz,
   when I compile,there is a question like follow：

   ```
   /usr/include/eXosip2/eX_call.h:217:7: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct osip_message_t *’
   ```

   src/common_exosip_event_handler.c:270:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘eXosip_call_send_answer’
   In file included from /usr/include/eXosip2/eXosip.h:43:0,
                    from src/includes.h:14,
                    from src/common_exosip_event_handler.c:23:
   /usr/include/eXosip2/eX_call.h:217:7: note: declared here
   Makefile:41: recipe for target 'obj/common_exosip_event_handler.o' failed
   make: *** [obj/common_exosip_event_handler.o] Error 1

Comment: if there is some solutions about the  uctimsclient,it will be great!

Comment: I solved the uctismclient problem  by installing ubuntu12 with a default gcc version of 4.6.3